# Optimizing Saponification Time for Oil Residue Removal from Fabrics with Sodium Carbonate (Na2CO3) at Different Temperatures

Tags: saponification

community,

I'm delving into the specifics of using $\ce{Na2CO3}$ for cleaning fabrics, specifically aiming at optimizing the saponification process to remove oil residues. Given the nature of the materials I'm dealing with, I'm considering two distinct temperature regimes: 80°C for cotton fabrics, and 40°C for synthetic fabrics, to prevent damage.

My objective is to find the optimum settings for two variables: concentration and reaction time, in order to achieve the most effective saponification process. Avoiding letting the fabric soak overnight in 20% concentration solution if 15 min at 5% were enough.

I'm sure such basic problematic has been covered somewhere in the scientific literature but I'm enable to find some answers using google scholar, maybe because I'm a total noob in chemistry and I might not use the right keywords.

Comment: Sodium carbonate (aka "washing soda") is Na2CO3 (resp. Na2CO3 . 10 H2O), while NaHCO3 (aka "baking soda") is sodium bicarbonate (hydrogencarbonate)

Comment: I assume you cannot avoid relying on empirical experience from sources related to cloth washing industry, or personal experience.

Comment: thanks I edited it